# Fail to run explain plan in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-execution-plan

The SQL is:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM table1
```

Privilege should be granted:

```
GRANT ALL ON sys.plan_table TO dbAccount
```

It leads to the following Error

SQL Error: ORA-01039:
01039. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges on underlying objects of the view"
*Cause:    Attempting to explain plan on other people's view without
           the necessary privileges on the underlying objects of the view.
*Action:   Get necessary privileges or do not perform the offending operation.

Comment: Does it related to grant read or select privilege to all view?

Answer (score 0):

The “`ORA-01039`: insufficient privileges on underlying objects of the view” message actually means that you don’t have privileges to access the `BASE OBJECTS` that used to build the view, not that you don’t have privileges to use the VIEW itself.

For example, if you have this view:

```
Create view tejash.V1 as select * from tejash.Table1

/

Grant all on tejash.V1 to ITpeople;
/
```

and if you are logging in as ITpeople, you have the privileges to access tejash.V1 but not to access tejash.Table1 directly.

Normally ITpeople can select the data from view i.e. run a SQL like this

```
Select * from tejash.V1
```

you don’t need privileges to access the underlying object (i.e. tejash.Table1). But in Oracle, if you tried to Explain Plan the same SQL, you would need privileges to access the underlying objects. If you don't have that permission then you will find this error.

**Demo:**

-- Creating view From user TEJASH and giving select rights on view to the user T

```
SQL> CREATE VIEW V1 AS
  2      SELECT
  3          *
  4      FROM
  5          EMP;

View created.

SQL> GRANT SELECT ON V1 TO T;

Grant succeeded.
```

-- Trying to select on view and also explain plan on the view(fail) From user T

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM TEJASH.V1;

        ID NAME           SALARY DEPT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 shubham          1000 comp
         2 vijay            5000 civil

SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM TEJASH.V1;
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM TEJASH.V1
                                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01039: insufficient privileges on underlying objects of the view
```

-- Giving select grant of the table also from user TEJASH to T

```
SQL> GRANT SELECT ON EMP TO T;

Grant succeeded.
```

-- Doing explain plan from user T now succeded.

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM TEJASH.V1;

Explained.
```

Cheers!!

Comment: So view must be created and granted access for explain plan of all tables?

Comment: You must have select privilige of all the underlying tables of the view to fetch plan

Comment: Does it related to grant read or select privilege to all view?

Comment: The grant is SELECT.